# How to execute a function after another one that has an onload function inside it?

Tags: javascript, canvas, onload, onload-event

- I want to **display an image**(dinamically) on the canvas and then **reset** it.
- **drawImage()** is the function that draws the image on the canvas after its source is **loaded**.
- **resetCanvas()** is the function that resets/clean the canvas.

  ```
  var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  drawImage("img/earth.jpg");
  resetCanvas();
  //more code

  function resetCanvas() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  function drawImage(source) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
          var x = img.width;
          var y = img.height;
          adjustCanvasSize(x, y);
          ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, x, y);
      }
      img.src = source;
  }
  ```

> When I execute this code, the **resetCanvas()** is "ignored". I don't want to insert the **resetCanvas()** inside the onload function of the **drawImage()** as it actually represents many other distinct functions and instructions that are going to be executed after the **drawImage()** and it would look wrong.

I was thinking if there was a way of making javascript more patient and stop it from executing anything until the image gets loaded in the drawImage function.

Comment: `and it would look wrong.` Actually, that sounds like the perfect solution, it sounds just fine to me. If you have many images that need to load first before resetting, then use Promises and `Promise.all`

Comment: You can have a variable boolean called like: var imageLoaded = false; and then when the image is loaded set it to true, but since the image loading is happening on another thread you can be in a while loop that's constantly checking to se if imageLoaded is true and it won't proceed until so.

Comment: My solution is probably not favorable but it is a way to accomplish what you want

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

1. If you reset the canvas after drawing the image you you won't see the image since the `resetCanvas` function is deleting everything you previously draw on the canvas
2. There are some problems when working with images in canvas. Please read this article: [MDM Using images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images)

Next come my code. I hope it helps.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
resetCanvas();
drawImage("https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/404.svg");

//more code

function resetCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function drawImage(source) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        var x = img.width;
        var y = img.height;
        adjustCanvasSize(canvas,x, y);
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, x, y);
    }
    img.src = source;
}


function adjustCanvasSize(canvas, x, y){
  canvas.width = x;
  canvas.height = y;  
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
```